# Ajax, javascript send variable to another page, on click

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Lests say I have a basic loop:

```
<? $count = 0; 

while ( $count < 20 ):      
$count++; ?>

**$page = 'unique value which changes every time it counts, it loops';**

<a href="http://www.mysite.com/page.php">Link<? echo $count; ?></a>

<? endwhile; ?>
```

I need a ajax/javascript code (does not matter really) for when **I click** lets say link nr 16 (displayed from the while loop) it sends me the $page variable with the content for link nr. 16. Not really sure how to make myself understood :( 
Sorry if my q sounds unclear.

**Please, no php methonds, not get or session variables**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok,from what i understand, you need a javascript function binded on the onclick event of the generated links that sends you back to a different page the link content.
if that's what you need, i recommend using a library such as jquery (it's more easy ti use) and paste this code into the page:
`$('a').click(function(){

   $.post("url_of_the_page_you_want_to_send",

   {data : $(this).html()});
});`
hope this helps :|

Answer (score 0):

I think you are talking about the get variables

Try this.

```
<a href="http://www.mysite.com/page.php?page=<? echo $page; ?>">Link<? echo $count; ?></a>
```

and you can get the value of `$page` variable in `page.php` like this

```
echo $_GET['page']
```

Comment: Not php, get or session variables. Just an axaj, jquery, javascript method, pleaseee

Comment: sorry, i am not much clear about your question

Comment: send a variable on click, thro javascript or ajax