# Variable from one page to another using ajax, jquery or javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ajax, javascript send variable to another page, on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4569982/ajax-javascript-send-variable-to-another-page-on-click)

Hello,
Lets say i have 3 divs:

```
<div id="section1">
<? $var='value1'; ?>
<a href="mysite.com/page1">page1</a>
</div>

<div id="section2">
<? $var='value2'; ?>
<a href="mysite.com/page2">page2</a>
</div>

<div id="section3">
<? $var='value3'; ?>
<a href="mysite.com/page1">page3</a>
</div>
```

Using jquery, javascript, ajax and not php (get, session variable) can i do this?
If i click on the link to page1 send $var='value1' to page1
If i click on the link to page2 send $var='value2' to page2
If i click on the link to page3 send $var='value3' to page3

Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ajax, javascript send variable to another page, on click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4569982/ajax-javascript-send-variable-to-another-page-on-click) Seems to be the same as your previous question. Please clarify, update and comment on your original question instead of creating a new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you're asking, but it sounds like you just want to supply the values on the query string to the destination pages:

```
<div id="section1">
<? $var='value1'; ?>
<a href="mysite.com/page1?var=<? echo $var; ?>">page1</a>
</div>

<div id="section2">
<? $var='value2'; ?>
<a href="mysite.com/page2?var=<? echo $var; ?>">page2</a>
</div>

<div id="section3">
<? $var='value3'; ?>
<a href="mysite.com/page1?var=<? echo $var; ?>">page3</a>
</div>
```

Then in each of those pages you'd use `$_GET['var']` to access the variable in the PHP code, or [access the query string from JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-querystring-values-with-jquery) directly.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a cookie. Get/set cookie functions at: http://www.w3schools.com/JS/js_cookies.asp